# Python multiprocessing - mp.Pool.join takes increasingly longer time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have encountered this problem in which mp.Pool.join() takes more and more time over each iteration. I am unable to recreate the problem on a smaller testcase, but I give the flow of my implementation here. Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

```
while (ftime < etime):
    results = []
    pool = mp.Pool(10)
    for tid in tracks:
        results.append(pool.apply_async(processTrack, args=(tid, df, tracksH)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for i in range(0, len(tracks)):
        if (results[i].ready()):
            gotresults = results[i].get()
            insertrows = gotresults[0]
            updaterows = gotresults[1]
    ftime = ftime + oneminute
```

The time taken by the pool.join() call is as follows:

```
Iteration    Time (s)
    1         1.52
    2         7.58
    3        11.36
    4        19.23
    5        27.78
    6        34.32
    7        51.59
```

Comment: Use a context manager to handle your pool. More importantly, why are you creating a pool inside of a loop?! It’s probably unnecessary, and, as you can tell from your timings, _really_ expensive.

Comment: This is the reason I am creating a pool inside of a loop: I have to use a .join() to make sure all tasks ended. If I do a join before a close, I get an error:   File "match.py", line 1069, in main
    pool.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 545, in join
    assert self._state in (CLOSE, TERMINATE). On the other hand, if I close the pool, I am not able to access it on the next round:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 355, in apply_async
    raise ValueError("Pool not running")
ValueError: Pool not running

Comment: I don’t think that moving the pool creation would lead to any issues of that sort. What I meant is to have a `with mp.Pool() as:` **outside** of the `while`. It’s difficult to know the specifics without seeing more of the program, but I’m quite confident that most of the snippet you shared can be simplified drastically. In conclusion, then, can you share more of your code (please see: [mcve])? I should be able to diagnose the answer, refactor the whole thing, and produce an answer, tomorrow :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint on trying to use context manager. I will debug the insides of processTrack further today and if it is still a problem will work on creating an example.

Comment: There was indeed a bottleneck in processTrack which caused some particular threads to finish slow. mp.Pool is no longer a problem now. I will use a context manager, though. Thanks much.